# I’m trying to write a python program for an avg call/array comparison that prints the avg plus any of the array values over 20% of the avg

Tags: python

Please see the code listed below for clarification

```
Def AvgCalc(test)
    Return sum(test) / Len (test)

    test = [2,4,3,10,33]
    Answer = AvgCalc(test)
    Print(“Avg is “ + answer + )
    if test[0] > (answer*1.2)
    Print test[0]
    if test[1] > (answer*1.2)
    Print test[1]
    if test[2] > (answer*1.2)
    Print test[2]
    if test[3] > (answer*1.2)
    Print test[3]
    if test[4] > (answer*1.2$
    Print test[4]
```

Comment: Doesn't look like valid python syntax to begin with

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
def AvgCalc( values ):
    avg = sum( values ) / len( values )
    print( "Average is: " + str( avg ) )
    print( [ q for q in values if q > avg*1.2 ] )
    return avg
```

**For example**

```
>>> x = [79, 46, 49, 6, 7, 23, 96, 1, 76, 33, 94, 59, 12, 73, 61, 41, 47, 97, 1, 82]
>>> AvgCalc( x )
Average is: 49.15
[79, 96, 76, 94, 59, 73, 61, 97, 82]
49.15
```

If you really need each value over 20% to be printed on a separate line, change the last line of `AvgCalc` to

```
print( "\n".join( [ str(q) for q in values if q > avg*1.2 ] ) )
```

**Output**

```
>>> x = [79, 46, 49, 6, 7, 23, 96, 1, 76, 33, 94, 59, 12, 73, 61, 41, 47, 97, 1, 82]
>>> AvgCalc( x )
Average is: 49.15
79
96
76
94
59
73
61
97
82
49.15
```